# How to use jquery steps wizard with right to left steps

Tags: jquery, css, right-to-left, wizard, jquery-steps

I'm using [jquery-steps](http://www.jquery-steps.com) plugin to make a wizard, but the problem is I can not make the steps right to left aligned.

.e.g: my steps: 1.step one 2.step two
my expectation: 2.step two 1.step on  (also i'm using an rtl language :) )

note: i'm using dynamically jquery step make with  ([You can check it here](http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples#vertical))

I tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#wizard").steps(
    rtl: true
  );
});
```

but didn't work, how can I solve it? Regards

Comment: Have you tried this? https://jsfiddle.net/2quw4hea/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried this : ?

```
.wizard>.steps>ul>li, .wizard>.actions>ul>li {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Tried it, was not enough for me.

Comment: can you share your code ? maybe thats a different case @BenyaminShoham

Answer (score 2):

for smart wizard jquery v4.x add this css

```
.sw-main .sw-container .step-content {
direction: rtl;
text-align: justify;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is my CSS for switching jQuery.steps right to left:

```
body {
    direction: rtl;
}

.wizard>.steps>ul>li, .wizard>.actions>ul>li {
    float: right;
}

.wizard > .content > .body {
    direction: rtl;
}
.wizard > .content > .body p {
    text-align: right;
}
```